# How to pull specific data out of JSON weather api

Tags: php, json

I found some (most) of the following code on wunderground and it works.  I can't figure out how to directly pull out specific information.  Here's the code that will run as is:

```
<?php 


function iterate($name, $object)
{
   foreach ($object as $key => $value)
   {
      if (is_object($value))
      {
         iterate("${name}->${key}", $value);
      }
      else if (is_array($value))
      {
         $n = count($value);
         for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)
         {
            if (is_object($value[$i]))
            {
               iterate("${name}->${key}[$i]", $value[$i]);
            }
            else
            {
              print "${name}->${key}[$i] = '$value'\n";
              echo "<br>";
            }
         }
      }
      else
      {
          print "${name}->${key} = '$value'\n";
          echo "<br>";
          print "${name}->${key} = '$value'\n";
          print "$name->$key\n";
          print_r ($value);
          echo "<br> <br>";
      }
    }
```

}

```
$api = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api';
$key = 'a66c7dca62f80c59'; // 
$features = 'geolookup/forecast10day'; // your desired features here
$query = 'q/MA/KBOS'; // your query here
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("$api/$key/$features/q/$query.json"));


iterate('data', $data);
```

Now's here the code that I added but is not working:

```
   $test = $data->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday[4]'}->{'fcttext'};
   print "$test";
```

?>

I've decoded the json query into $data but how do I get at a specific piece of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$api = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api';
$key = 'a66c7dca62f80c59'; //
$features = 'geolookup/forecast10day'; // your desired features here
$query = 'q/MA/KBOS'; // your query here
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("$api/$key/$features/q/$query.json"),1);

echo $data['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'][4]['fcttext'];
```

of course in the real world you'd' would want to check that all this stuff exists before referencing any of it

```
$forecastdays = $data['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'];

foreach ($forecastdays as $forecastday){
    echo $forecastday['fcttext'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've been playing around with this and just learning about associative arrays.  I found using the true option in decode makes the syntax a little easier [] instead of ->.  also the print_r(array_keys($data)); helps a lot.  I didn't realize that you had to do that for each level of the array you go down or deeper.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$data[0]->{'forecast'}
```

Also if you prefer associative arrays, just add true as a second argument to your [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), and you can access your data like so:

```
$data[0]['forecast']
```

PS. showing us a portion of the JSON will make it easier for us to help you solve your problem.

Comment: i did try $data[0]->{'forecast'}  but it doesn't work. and I tried $data[0]->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday[4]'}->{'fcttext'};  and that doesn't work either.  any ideas?

Comment: the entire code is listed above and will run except at the end which I'm trying to solve with a little help from my friends....'